# Swift: Simple Animation?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard

I have a button and a textview on my VC.
The textview is automatically hidden.

```
textview.hidden = true
```

If i press the button, the textview shows up.

```
 @IBAction func ButtonIsPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    textview.hidden = false

}
```

Is there a way to add a simple "fade" animation to the textview?

I mean if i press the button, the textview should fade in.

I heard about [facebooks pop](https://github.com/facebook/pop) Framework, but isn't there a much easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//Instead of textview.hidden = true

```
  textview.alpha = 0
```

//Now on press action

```
 @IBAction func ButtonIsPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

 UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: { () -> Void in
      self.textview.alpha = 1.0
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But i got one question: What is alpha for?

Comment: it is related to transperancy range from 0.0~1.0

Answer (score 0):

You could get simple fade in/fade out with alpha value of view.

```
// fade out
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.15, delay: 0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {
    textview.alpha = 0;
}, completion: { finished in
    textview.hidden = YES;
});

// fade in
textview.hidden = NO;
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.15, delay: 0, options: .CurveEaseIn, animations: {
    textview.alpha = 1;
}, completion: { finished in
    // something you need
});
```